# Why do I receive the Partial datatype?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code snippet:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Text
import Data.Attoparsec.Text

data GreetingYear = GreetingYear Text Int deriving Show


greetingYearParser :: Parser GreetingYear
greetingYearParser = GreetingYear <$> (string "hello" <|> string "bye")  
                                  <*> decimal
```

When I use it as follows:

```
parse greetingYearParser "hello172"
```

I've got

```
Partial _
```

Why do I not receive:

```
Done "" (GreetingYear "hello" 172)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attoparsec builds incremental parsers. The `parse` function does not assume it's been given all the input , only a chunk of it. If the next chunk of input started with `"32"` , there would be more to include in the parsed `decimal`. I think you probably want `parseOnly` instead of `parse`, which makes the additional assumption that it's been given the full remaining input.

Comment: I did not understand, what do you mean with **there would be more to include in the parsed decimal**. With `feed (parse greetingYearParser "hello172") "34"`, why I still get the `Partial`?

Comment: The `greetingYearParser` function is a type `Parser` and it should work with the `parse` function. Why for example `parse (string "hello") "hello"` works?

Comment: could you please explain it with an example?

Comment: You still get `Partial` because the `decimal` parser doesn't have a state where it both matches and doesn't accept more input.  The `string` parser is different - once it matches, it no longer accepts more input, so it's done.  The only way you can get a `Done` result from a parser that ends with `decimal` is to tell the parser the input is finished.  That's what `parseOnly` does.

Comment: You've already got all the examples that can help.  What you need is to think about the question "When does a parser know it's done?"